# PropertyChanged for multiple index values

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, inotifypropertychanged, indexed-properties

To raise a `PropertyChanged` event for an indexer and a particular index value, do this:

```
OnPropertyChanged(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Item[{0}]", indexValue));
```

But what if the indexer accepts multiple index values?  Rather than `Item[{0}]`, what should the format string look like?  Is it `Item[{0},{1},{3}]` or perhaps `Item[{0}][{1}][{3}]`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be `Item[{0},{1}...]` because the second case is a jagged style indexing, or think of it as "array of arrays". Your class would only take the first argument, then whatever it returned would index on the second, and so-forth. If your class handles all the indexes, then the proper format would be the first one.

Comment: @RonBeyer Right, `Item[{0},{1},{3}]` has to be it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar where I passed in multiple values to a function that was subscribed to `OnPropertyChanged` and just used some char to parse the items.

If I understand correctly you're just trying to get those values correct?

You could do:

```
 OnPropertyChanged(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Item[{0}];Item[{1}];Item[{2}]", indexValue, indexValue1, indexValue2));
```

Then just parse on `;` using:

```
string[] stringArray = yourString.Split(';')
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't want to invent my own property name format. I want to use the format that XAML bindings will understand.

Comment: Oops sorry didn't notice the XAML tag.